# A math related Puzzle(?!)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

In our university somebody posted this:

**BTHGIR ENIKLN   CGEKAR   ODEPWU   MONOTT   ESLEFT**

The background of the whole thing has a grid-like pattern. Can somebody decipher this? It's somehow math related cause we will be celebrating math day this March.

[image: That's the pic for your reference]

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to say in what language it is.

Comment: Well it's code. The official language here is english. So..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The message is

> KEEP WALKING - DO NOT TURN. RIGHT BECOMES LEFT.

If we arrange the letters in

> a 6x6 grid, we can read the letters spiraling outward
>
>  [image]

Comment: Brilliant! Could you tell me how you did that?

Comment: @technophyle I noticed right away the first letters of each group spelled out `BECOME`, then when I arranged the "words" as in the image, I noticed the words all around the outer edge, and `PEEK`/`KEEP` in the center... at that point it just clicked.